# What does asp-for do behind the scenes?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have this code in a .cshtml file:

```
<label asp-for="Email">Your email:</label>
```

What is going on behind the scenes when this gets parsed?

I can see that `asp-for` actually calls `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.LabelTagHelper.For`.

But what implementation of `IHtmlGenerator` is passed in to the `LabelTagHelper` constructor?

In a .NET console app, I could just open up the .exe in ILSpy to see what's going on.

How can I do the same thing for an Asp.net Core app?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the LableTagHelper source code:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/LabelTagHelper.cs

`IHtmlGenerator` is passed into constructor and generate lable tag

```
var tagBuilder = Generator.GenerateLabel(
            ViewContext,
            For.ModelExplorer,
            For.Name,
            labelText: null,
            htmlAttributes: null);
```

Update:

The default Asp.net Core MVC avoid direct dependencies as much as possible.Rather than hard-code an implementation of the `IHtmlGenerator` interface,Asp.net Core MVC loads an implementation that is dependency injected during the application initialization process.When the view engine create an interface of `IHtmlHelper`, it passes the `IHtmlGenerator` instance via the constructor.

Refer to [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=K141DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=implementation%20class%20of%20IHtmlGenerator&source=bl&ots=yx46-5yhu2&sig=ACfU3U1UfcrCzpmTl8VNQzSpGUbbzT9EbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjsJLx6LXjAhWb63MBHZh6AMkQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=implementation%20class%20of%20IHtmlGenerator&f=false)

Comment: But an implementation of IHtmlGenerator needs to be passed in, what is that implementation class?

Comment: The default implementation of `IHtmlGenerator` is [DefaultHtmlGenerator](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs).I dig it and find something, please see my update answer.